# ImportError: No module named utils_datagen

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to run Martin Gorner's `GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-without-a-phd 00_RNN_predictions_playground.ipynb` and get an `ImportError` for both `import utils_datagen` and `import utils_display`.

I get the same error running `tensorflow/tensorflow` Python 2 and `Jupiter/tensorflow-notebook` running Python 3. I am running macOS Sierra 10.13.3 and Docker Client: Version: 18.03.1-ce

How do I access `utils_datagen` or work around it?
Thanks

Lew

```
import numpy as np
import utils_datagen
import utils_display
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow version: " + tf.__version__)
print("Hello World and Lew 30 May")
```

And get:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0f00155f1447> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import utils_datagen
      3 import utils_display
      4 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
      5 import tensorflow as tf

ImportError: No module named utils_datagen
```

Comment: Have you put `utils_datagen` and other scripts under the "current working directory" of your notebook (os.getcwd())? Can you import `utils_datagen` from its directory in python interpreter?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do what you are asking.  I did the following:

Comment: I entered $which python. and got /Users/lewleib/anaconda3/bin/python.   Then entered$ python -V. and got Python 3.6.4 : : Anaconda, Inc. However that is on the host. My problem is in a Docker container.

Comment: I'm not sure how the Docker container will affect your run (like can you `mv` scripts in your docker)? Here is what I catch for now: `utils_datagen` is not a installed conda or pip module. It is a script coming together with `00_RNN_predictions_playground.ipynb`. You need to put `utils_datagen` [where python can find](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching).

Comment: Thank you @Y. Luo. In trying to simplify my file string, I only partially cloned the Gorner GitHub file into my host file and missed the utils_datagen file. Now python can find it.  How do I reward you?

Comment: Getting your feedback and knowing I'm helpful is good enough for rewarding. Enjoy your coding!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by comment from @Y. Luo. In trying to simplify my file string, I only partially cloned the Gorner GitHub file into my host file and missed the utils_datagen file. Now python can find it.

Close this thread.